# cx_Oracle installation fails with FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3]

Tags: python, setup.py, cx-oracle

My organisation does not allow me to use pip to install Python libraries, hence i downloaded the zip for cx_Oracle (python-cx_Oracle-master.zip) from GIT and then tried to install it using install command, as below :

```
python.exe ./setup.py install
```

However, it immediately fails with below error :

```
  File ".\setup.py", line 91, in <module>
    for n in sorted(os.listdir(dpiSourceDir)) if n.endswith(".c")]
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'odpi\\src'
```

I tried to brain storm a lot but could not reach to conclusion. While cx_Oracle is important for me to proceed in my project, i cannot find a way forward. Requesting help from you guys.

I'm on a Windows10 x64 machine, with Python 3.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the ODPI-C source code. You need to follow the instructions found in the documentation [here](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#install-using-github).

Comment: Thank you @Anthony , downloading the ODPI-C source code, it did not give mw the error. However, is still gave me an error that, "error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required" . Since i am not allowed to download exe from internet, need to figure this out.

Comment: You will require a compiler in order to build cx_Oracle. How you get that compiler is entirely up to you!

Comment: Hello @Anthony, Could you please elaborate, what kind of compiler i would require ? I already installed  Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 driver and still have the same issue . :(

Comment: That compiler will work. What is the "same" issue? The original one you mentioned should be resolved!

Comment: I get you now. Maybe i need a C++ compiler to get this working. As of now i just got access to drivers, and hence getting   "error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required". Thank you :)